# Java regex to replace special character, one or more spaces and period with special character and period

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

```
See it now! .5..%..off your purchase!.Only today.
```

I would like it to be

```
See it now! 5% off your purchase! Only today.
```

Which is:

every special character followed by zero or more spaces and one or more periods, will be replaced with the special character and a space. In case of a number and 2 periods, it will be replace with spaces only

How can I do it?

Comment: Please define "special character"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\Try this

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\B[ .]+", " ");
```

This matches one or more spaces or periods which are preceded by a non-word boundary. These are then replaced by a single space.

**Edit**

Based on the amended question:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\B[ .]+|(\\d)\\.+", "$1 ");
```

Also matches a digit followed by one or more periods. The periods are replaced by a single space.

Comment: Good idea and works on the example string. It will however also match multiple whitespace (independent of punctuation characters), which may not be desired. But +1 for word boundaries.

Comment: This was actually better for me - since also leading periods were removed

Comment: It's still not perfect. Because if I have the sentence "Exclusive offer..20..%.. Try it Now." I would like it to be "Exclusive offer. 20% Try it Now." Your solutions make it be "Exclusive offer. 20. % " (there is no need for period-space after the 20 number

Comment: @Odelya: That was not part of your original spec (you wrote "a period", not "one or more periods"). Could you edit your question to state precisely what the rules for matching/not matching are?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll(
    "(?x)      # verbose regex                             \n" +
    "(\\p{P})  # Match and capture a punctuation character \n" +
    "\\ *      # Match zero or more spaces                 \n" +
    "\\.       # Match a dot", "$1 ");
```

Comment: what is the verbose regex for?

Comment: The `(?x)` flag allows me to add comments to the regex.